# При каком разрешении здесь делать моб. меню?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, меню

Если header останется таким же, какой и был всё будет супер, но если например вместо Shop прописать более длинное слово меню рушится. Нужно уточнять у заказчика будет ли меню изменятся или делать его не при 768, а при 1024?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: R]

Comment: _«Нужно уточнять у заказчика будет ли меню изменятся или делать его не при 768, а при 1024?»_ - этот вопрос ведь совсем не технического характера (ответ на него, в первую очередь, определяется договором с заказчиком). Если совесть призывает внести улучшения не по ТЗ/макету, то это безусловно стоит сделать... морально подготовившись к тому, что заказчик впоследствии может потребовать убрать улучшающие правки (даже после их согласования).

Comment: Не нужно. Есть макет, есть ТЗ - делаете в полном соответствии. Если заказчик что-то не предусмотрел (в том числе длину пунктов меню) - это его проблемы. Любые доработки и переделки - за доп.плату. Учитесь ценить свой труд и своё время.

Comment: Есть только декстоп версия